# Error - The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

If I create a brand new Website project using Visual Studio 2010 dot net 4.0 I get this error message if I try to add "using System.Web.Extensions".

```
The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'
```

I do not get the error if I create a website using dot net 3.5

Any searching I have done suggest changing from target platform 4.0 Client Profile to just plain 4.0

But I don't have Client Profile as an option and C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.Extensions.dll is on my PC.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add the dll as a reference to the project?

Comment: There is no namespace `System.Web.Extensions` in `System.Web.Extensions.dll`. Why do you need this namespace for?

Comment: can you post a screen shot of your project properties, where the target profile is displayed? I have had this same problem many times and it has always been target platform. Might be worth a second look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a reference to System.Web.Extensions in order to use it in your project.

[image: Adding System.Web.Extensions]

Comment: Unfortunately in my case it didn't work after adding that reference.

Comment: Are you getting exactly the same error: `The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'`?

Comment: My issue was similar, because I'm doing a WPF application. Adding the Extensions reference was not enough for Intelisense to detect what `using` I needed in order to instantiate `JavaScriptSerializer`. I later found out I needed to add `using System.Web.Script.Serialization;` and then it finally worked :) +1 for you!