# C# 'Extensions' does not exist in 'System.Web'

Tags: c#

If I try adding `using System.Web.Extensions;` into my code, I get the following error message:

```
The type of namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I have already enabled 'System.Web.Extensions' under Project -> Add Reference -> Assemblies -> Framework.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error - The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952614/error-the-type-or-namespace-name-extensions-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace)

Try restarting VS